# Entity Frramework Core publishing to Azure database not working

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to Azure and EF Core. I am required to publish localhost app to Azure. I am using EF Core with a database-first approach. The database is working if I run on localhost, but after deploying to Azure, the database is not working. I created an Azure SQL database but that's not working, I don't know what to do. I am using Visual Studio, ASP.NET Core web app with react template.

Here is the [Azure link](https://projectnavonboard.azurewebsites.net/show-products)

And here is [github repo](https://github.com/navjotnabha/onboardingProject)

EDIT:
in my `appsettings.json` there is no connection string but inside my `dbContext` I have:

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => 
      optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Navbase;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=Yes");
```

When I try to update database in publish Azure SQL, I get this error:

> Unable to update database with latest migration for DbContext 'Project1.Models.NavbaseContext'.
> Error: dotnet ef database update --context Project1.Models.NavbaseContext

Comment: please paste the whole error, if you are not seeing full error message, try enable verbose so the framework print out more things in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your db is pointed to your local SQL Server not to Azure SQL db, maybe you can change that first. If you haven't create Azure SQL instance in Azure, do that first then get the connection string.

here's few things you should do

1. store the db connection string in appsetting for better control
2. if you are using Azure, store that db connection in azure app service configuration, that way if your code is published in public repo, no one else would know about it

Comment: hi thanks,but connection string is not store in app settings. and even if i put azure connection string there still it doesn't work

Comment: any error you're getting? you should be able to debug locally first, if local can then in azure also should be ok..

Comment: another setting to look at is at the azure sql setting, either you whitelist the app service IP or enable access by Azure services